# design api for different types and strategy in java

Tags: java, image, algorithm

I am trying to develop some codes of image processing.
I want to design a different API which could support different type,
like int, double, float, char and others without the help of dynamic polymorphism
Because I find out that when you deal with image processing, dynamic polymorphism
would slow you down, use primitive types like int or char is the fastest
solution, but it is very inconvenient when I want to design different API according
to those types.

Besides, I want to do something like this without the burden of dynamic polymorphism

```
public static void convert_color(
        final int[] sp, final int[] dp,
        final int Xres, final int Yres,
                    Strategy strategy)
{
    \\....
}
```

Some algorithms would suffer from the performance penalty of strategy(dynamic polymorphism)
I need to copy and paste just because the strategy are differents.

It is very difficult to design a high performance and flexibility image processing with
my current level, do you have a better solution to gain performance and flexibility?

Comment: *"polymorohism"* everywhere instead of *"polymorphism"*?  Now that is weird: I just tried to edit another question where every single instance of the word *"iteration"* was written *"itertaion"*.  I can understand a typo once, but making the same typo five times in a row is weird.  It's even weirder that another question had the same issue with another word...

Comment: Sorry, there are same mistakes because I copy and paste

Comment: Performance hit from polymorphism is very small. 
For any image processing you should be more worried about allocations, spatial and temporal locality of code and data and primitive type boxing.
Trove4j (i.e. using collections with primitive types) will help you to avoid any boxing of primitive types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you at how [Trove4j](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/) solves this problem as it generates collections for primitives. You can also use their collections.

I would start with a "super type" e.g. `double` and optimise the code where you find it makes a difference.

Comment: Trove4j is using a custom pre-processor or 'macro' system and does code generation from a 'template' for all the primitives right IIRC right!?   Basically the kind of stuff that everyone told us, since the first days of Java, that *"You'll never ever need that"* ; )

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a viable solution.I hope it could handle the case of strategy too